# an array from genfromtxt is being passed as a sequence?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, errorbar

I have a list of coordinates and their respective error values in the shape:

```
# Graph from standard correlation, page 1
1.197   0.1838  -0.03504    0.07802 +-0.006464  +0.004201
1.290   0.2072  -0.04241    0.05380 +-0.005833  +0.008101
```

where the columns denote `x,y,lefterror,righterror,buttomerror,toperror`I load the file as `error=np.genfromtxt("standard correlation.1",skip_header=1)` and finally I try to graph this as

```
xerr=error[:,2:4]
yerr=error[:,4:]
x=error[:,0]
y=error[:,1]
plt.errorbar(x,y,xerr=xerr,yerr=yerr,fmt='')
```

Which yells a `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`when I try to run it, I understand this error is given when you're passing an object such a a list to an argument that's expecting a numpy array object, I am clueless as to how I should fix this problem, as np.genfromtxt should always return an ndarray.

Thanks for your help.

**Edit:** I changed the file to remove the '+' character, as reading '+-' would yield NaN values in the bottom error column, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Print `error`.  Also show us its `shape` and `dtype`.  When using `genfromtxt` it is a good idea to look at what it produces before trying to use it.

Comment: using `print np.shape(x),np.shape(y),np.shape(xerr),np.shape(yerr), type(datos)` I get `(30,) (30,) (30, 2) (30, 2) <type 'numpy.ndarray'>` also, the error is on the line from the plt.errorbar() which I specified above

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to hpaulj I noticed that the error bars' shape was (30,2), however `plt.errobar()` expects error arrarys in the shape (2,n), as python usually transposes matrices in similar operations and automatically avoids this problem I figured it would also do it, but I decided to change lines the following way:

```
xerr=error[:,2:4]
yerr=error[:,4:]
```

into

```
xerr=np.transpose(error[:,2:4])
yerr=np.transpose(error[:,4:])
```

which made the script run properly, although I still don't understand why the previous code gave me such an error, if anyone can help me clear that up I'll appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The shape of the array numpy expects for individual errorbars is `(2, N)`. You therefore need to transpose your array `error[:,2:4].T`
Also, `matplotlib.errorbar` understands those values relative to the data. If `x` is the value and `(xmin, xmax)` the corresponding error, the errorbar goes from `x-xmin` to `x+xmax`. You therefore shouldn't have negative values in the errorbar arrays.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = "1   0.1  0.05    0.1 0.005  0.01" + \
   " 1.197   0.1838  -0.03504    0.07802 -0.006464  0.004201 " + \
   " 1.290   0.2072  -0.04241    0.05380 -0.005833  0.008101" 
error=np.fromstring(f, sep=" ").reshape(3,6)
print error
#[[ 1.        0.1       0.05      0.1       0.005     0.01    ]
# [ 1.197     0.1838   -0.03504   0.07802  -0.006464  0.004201]
# [ 1.29      0.2072   -0.04241   0.0538   -0.005833  0.008101]]

xerr=np.abs(error[:,2:4].T)
yerr=np.abs(error[:,4:].T)
x=error[:,0]
y=error[:,1]
plt.errorbar(x,y,xerr=xerr,yerr=yerr,fmt='')
plt.show()
```

Concerning the value error, it may have been caused by the `+-` issue.